Select and copy all paragraphs in selection range word macro
I need all paragraphs that are selected and not even completely selected to be selected and copied. I just wouldn’t like to select them completely with the mouse and copy them.
I know how to select and copy one paragraph:
Sub Copy()
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select

If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
    Selection.Copy
End If
End Sub

but I need to select and copy all the paragraphs that are somehow affected in the selection.

Something like
Dim r As Word.Range
Set r = Selection.Range
r.Expand wdParagraph
' If you actually need to copy, but maybe you could use r.FormattedText, depending on what you're trying to do.
' If you don't want to copy the paragraph mark, uncomment the
' following line
' r.End = r.End - 1
r.Copy
' ...and eventually
Set r = Nothing


Is it possible to make it selection of these paragraphs and then copy, without the new line symbol ¶ in the last selected paragraph?
